# Webpacker and Rails, ReferenceError: xxxx is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

there is something i cannot understand in webpacker. 
I have my app in Rails with webpacker and I'm trying to integrate an external theme based on bootstrap.

I have my pack entry point defined

```
import Rails from 'rails-ujs';
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
import 'jquery';

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();

// Init
import 'admin/admin';
```

and the in my admin/admin.js I have my js scripts

```
// init global theme functions
import '../src/admin/framework/lib/util.js';
import '../src/admin/framework/lib/app.js';

// init global theme javascript
import '../src/admin/framework/components/foundation/menu/menu.js';

// init global user javascript
import '../admin/global/init';

// init page specific javascript
import '../admin/page_specific/init'
```

The problem is the order. Webpacker inserts for example util.js at the end of the compiled js file so I have a lot of reference error.

In the admin panel package there is a gulp task and of course the script are compiled in the right order.

```
"scripts": [
                            "{$config.path.src}/theme/framework/lib/util.js",
                            "{$config.path.src}/theme/framework/lib/app.js",
                            "{$config.path.src}/theme/framework/components/foundation/**/*.js",
                            "{$config.path.src}/theme/framework/components/base/**/*.js",
                            "{$config.path.src}/theme/demo/default/scripts/bundle/layout.js"
                        ]
```

Why webpacker in rails doesn't respect the order I put the file in my admin.js?